# Moving window based kernel density estimation

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, probability-density

I have a stream of data on which I want to estimate the kernel density(or a histogram). Input parameter is the window length. For example 60-seconds, or 5-minutes or a month. Any data older than the window size should affect the estimation minimally. However, I cannot store the actual data point. Once a new data sample arrives, I want to add it to the estimator and discard it. Since this is a resource constrained environment(both CPU+memory), the method should preferably be O(1) in space and time complexity.

Are there any readymade libraries that already do this job?
I would prefer something in GO, but I would take an implementation in any language.

If there are no existing implementations, is there an algorithm that I can refer to and implement?

(Searching on Google did not give me any direct answer, I am new to machine learning and statistics)

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically decaying histogram would do the job.

$$h(i) = h(i) * (1 - e^{-1/\tau}) + e^{-1/\tau} \delta(i-j)$$

where $j$ is the new observation, $h(i)$ is the running average histogram, and $\tau$ is the time constant.